# get count on a query with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've this code:

```
User.joins(:pets).select('users.*, COUNT(pets.id) as pets_count').group('user.id')
```

That returns a `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`. however I'm not able to fetch the value in the `pets_count` column of the resultset.

How can I access to that value? or what can I use in order to have the count from a join?

Comment: What you are getting after calling `users.first.pets_count` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking into the console, you'll see only user's attributes but after iterating you can call 'pets_count' on it.

For Ex:-

```
users = User.joins(:pets).select('users.*, COUNT(pets.id) as pets_count').group('user.id')

users.each do |user|
  user.pets_count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The **user** in *group* should be **users**:

```
@users = User.joins(:pets).select('users.*, COUNT(pets.id) as pets_count').group('users.id')
```

You can get the *pets_count* without any problem when you call `@users.first.pets_count`